# Perform the flickr badge code after page loads

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the flikr badge code (http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne) like so

```
<!-- Start of Flickr Badge -->
<div id="flickr_badge_uber_wrapper">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.flickr.com/badge_code_v2.gne?..."></script>
<p class="clear"><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/..." target="_blank" rel="external">see more...</a></p>
</div>
<!-- End of Flickr Badge -->
```

This works great, apart from it's near the top of the page and the flikr api will occasionally hang the rest of the site. To stop this I figure I could either move the html to the bottom of the page and use some extra css to stylise where I want it to go, or use some javascript to make it load later. The former sounds like it involves a bit too much absolute positioning, while I'm a little confused how to go about the latter.

Normally this would be easy, for example:

```
document.onload = function() {
   // Do something
}
```

But how do I do it with the flickr badge code, it's a link to dynamically produced javascript?

**EDIT**

The source from the link is i.e. the js pulled in:

```
var b_txt = '';

// write the badge

b_txt+= // some html, b_txt+= called for each image.

b_txt += '<span style="position:absolute;left:-999em;top:-999em;visibility:hidden" class="flickr_badge_beacon"><img src="http://geo.yahoo.com/p?s=792600102&t=53dd558c54466a104f77d195043a008d&r=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2F&fl_ev=0&lang=en&intl=uk" width="0" height="0" alt="" /></span>';

document.write(b_txt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a placeholder `<div>` where you want it to finally appear. Then use jquery `$(document).ready` and set the innerHTML of your placeholder div to the span/img/script tag. place the script tag near then end of the body, and it will load last. When everything is finished loading, document.ready will be fired

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(
     function(){
          $("#placeholder").innerHTML("<script/span/img>");
});
```

Comment: I think I understand - the placeholder is empty, run the script at the bottom of the page which will pull in the flickr generated html and then finally use a bit of javascript (jQuery) to move that into the placeholder?

Comment: Yes, you could let it load at the bottom, and then place it in the empty placeholder. Or, you could wait until the whole body has loaded, and then place the whole script in the place holder div and let it load there. Either of them should work fine!

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to pull the script tag out of the wrapper. Position the `flickr_badge_uber_wrapper` wherever you'd like it, and then place the javascript src call at the end of the body. I don't see a reason why the javascript couldn't be pulled from the wrapper and loaded later on page load. That should be the easiest way to keep your page from hanging.

Comment: See edit. The code run isn't intelligently choosing to place the html in the flickr_badge_uber_wrapper, it's just placing it there because that's where I've put the javascript src code. If I move that call to the bottom of the page, the pictures follow.